# get date in string php

Tags: php, date

I am trying to get the date out of sentences in php.. so for example

I am trying to get 10/8/2006 out of

"This building was cleaned on the 8th of October 2006 after a huge storm."

There is a github function for it
https://github.com/etiennetremel/PHP-Find-Date-in-String but it fails in dates such as 1/5/2012.

I realize that given the varied nature of date strings, finding a date string in strings is so much tougher than just simple REGEX for a specific format, or simply strototiming a given string input..

does anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: so if I'm correct the date format within the string can be anything? also dates like 3rd of March 2011 should be interpreted?

Comment: yes lol. it can be anything.. i have to code it, sort of looking for anything that's already out there..

Comment: Sounds like the way to go are regular expressions indeed. Lot's of them. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would start by looking for a few basic patterns and extracting them with a few passes of regular expression (mm/dd/yy and mm/dd/yyyy with `\d{2]/\d{2}/\d{2,4}`, then look for others, like `\d{1,2}(th|st|rd)? Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)` etc)

It will almost certainly be quicker to write a few regular expressions and do it in passes than write one massive one.

Then, pass the stuff you extracted in to `strtotime` to get yourself a usable unix timestamp and do with what you need from that.

Caveats:

- I haven't tried the regexes, there are obvious optimisations
- Works on the assumption that your dates will always be USA style (mm/dd/yy, and not dd/mm/yy)

Comment: thank you.. i didn't 'know there was the dd/mm/yy format. that may explain why that github failed.. probably not american

Comment: Yes, it's dd/mm/yy in the UK (possibly others too).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a working solution because 10/8/2010 is not telling too much... it can be 10 day or month... I think you can proceed with your regex :)

Answer (score 0):

i think it will be more simple with regex.
the problem is that aher ary many options of how the date is writen.

Comment: yeah i figure someone has already done it with the huge library of all the different ways and the associated regexes, but unforunately i havne't been able to find it online

Comment: its not to defcult.
preg_match the year is easy --> 4 digit number.
month by name is easy to, 12 options.
the problem is day of month how you now if its a month number or day number.